# Find a file in Lost+found directory

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss, data-corruption

I managed to get into the folder, and now I see these elements

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what they are (seem to residual traces of the pre-existing system Xubuntu), but my question is how I can see if between these fragments is a pdf file type that I want to recover (see my  previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671771/a-method-for-reading-residues-data-on-a-massacred-partition))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to recover the PDF file (if possible), then I suggest you go with `photorec` tool. You can install it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

### What is `lost+found` dir?

Information found on [TLDP Page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/lostfound.html)

> Linux should always go through a proper shutdown. Sometimes your
>   system might crash or a power failure might take the machine down.
>   Either way, at the next boot, a lengthy filesystem check (the speed of
>   this check is dependent on the type of filesystem that you actually
>   use. ie. ext3 is faster than ext2 because it is a journalled
>   filesystem) using fsck will be done. Fsck will go through the system
>   and try to recover any corrupt files that it finds. The result of this
>   recovery operation will be placed in this directory.

This link would be helpful as well:
[What is the purpose of the lost+found folder in Linux and Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix)

Comment: Instead of just linking that question, you could also include the most important and for this question relevant points into your own answer and leave the link as reference and to look up more details. This way you can improve your answer's quality and make it easier for future readers to quickly access the information they want.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks for the tip. Made an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Kenpachi, It seems the right answer. I understand from your link that lost+found contains inode, broken links and binary files, the names should generally be gone so it's impossible to find them directly, then I wonder if the items put in the lost+found must be active in some way, that is they are present (also pending delete) in some process, i.e.to be present in some process for positioning in lost + found (this I think I understand according to the link you gave me); if so, I do not think the pdf can be put into the directory

Comment: the command outputs a problem: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Now I am in Ubuntu live CD, 14.04

Comment: I think you may need to run `sudo apt-get update` if you are running from live cd and then try the command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28912/discussion-between-kenpachi-and-bento).